# How to use AWS Cognito with FastAPI authentication

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, amazon-cognito, fastapi

I'm trying to add authentication to a FastAPI application using AWS Cognito. I can get valid JSON responses from Cognito, including AccessToken and RefreshToken. Using the FastAPI Oauth2 examples I've seen has led me to create code like this:

```
@router.post("/token")
async def get_token(form_data: OAuth2PasswordRequestForm = Depends()):
    # get token from cognito
    response = await concurrency.run_in_threadpool(
        client.initiate_auth,
        ClientId=settings.aws_cognito_app_client_id,
        AuthFlow="USER_PASSWORD_AUTH",
        AuthParameters={
            "USERNAME": form_data.username,
            "PASSWORD": form_data.password,
        },
    )
     return response["AuthenticationResult"]["AccessToken"]

@router.post("/things")
async def things(token: str = Depends(oauth2_scheme)):
    return {"token": token}
```

This *seems* to work as the "/things" endpoint is only accessible if authorized through the OpendAPI authentication popup. However, two things:

1. The token value is "undefined" in the things() handler, why is that?
2. How do I get the RefreshToken to the user?

Any suggestions or ideas are welcome.